# To filter the wrong data of point positioning

Tags: point, filter, matlab, c

I have collected GPGGA data by Novatel OEMV receiver in static single point mode. I have so much data (GPGGA format) and I want to get the static point axis by averaging all data. But some of the data have big deviations so I need to filter the wrong data or data with big deviations before averaging all the data.

In all, how could I filter invalid data? Is there any C arithmetic program or Matlab arithmetic program?